# If an Object allocates dynamic memory from the heap, then how to design a destructor without some unwanted side effect?

Tags: c++, destructor, dynamic-memory-allocation, return-type, raii

So this is how the object looks like. A simple variable length array with an upper bound on the size.

```
class Queue
    {public:
        int *array;
        unsigned siz;//Indicates how many elements are there right now
        void print() const;
        Queue(unsigned len):array(new int[len]), siz(0) {} /*Constructor
        indicating the maximum length*/
        ~Queue(){delete[] array;}   //Destructor to free the memory
        };
    /*End of class definition */
Queue somefunction()
        {
            Queue sample(10);  //Allocates memory from heap
            .........
            return sample
        }
```

If  `somefunction` returns `sample` by value, does the dynamic memory get de-allocated as soon as `sample` goes out of scope? So what's the way out for the situation? I guess if I eliminate the destructor (or the delete command) then the function could work as I want. But will that cause memory leakage in other parts of the code?
I also feel somehow the question ties to the concept of RAII, but it is not clear to me. Is it possible to illustrate what RAII means in this example?

Comment: See "The rule of three".

Comment: write a copy constructor or move constructor, the caller of someFunction will then have the object on the stack and the internal pointer in the heap